# How to import custom fonts into an app or element using Polymer?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-2.x

How does one import custom fonts into a Polymer app or element?

Per @tweightman on the [Polymer Slack Channel](https://polymer.slack.com):

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/my-typography/my-typography.html">

<dom-module id="my-page-styles">
  <template>
    <style include="my-typography">
      :host {
        @apply --my-custom-font-mixin;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

> Stumbled across a possible solution: instead of using `@font-face` rules inside my-typography.html style module, I seem to have to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="my-font-face.css">` instead.

Comment: I am trying to find the right implementation to add new fonts to a polymer app and use as default font. Can you elaborate a little more your possible solution? What's inside my-typography.html?

Comment: @d.mares: I don't have a solution yet. [But here is a public version of a relative of the referenced file](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/typography.html). Please add an answer if you come up with one. Even if it doesn't work at least it might help spawn some ideas. https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-styles/blob/master/typography.html

Answer (score 2):

In my app shell entrypoint (`index.html`), I have:

```
<custom-style>
    <style is="custom-style">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
            src: url(/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }

        html {
            --primary-font-family: 'Space Mono', monospace;
        }
    </style>
</custom-style>
```

Then I just use the font like you would anywhere else, either as `var(--primary-font-family)` or just as `font-family: 'Space Mono'`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways, Either you can load font through html file or through custom element file. And everyone know how to do it in html file, just add the link onto head and use it in styles.

In custom elements also we do the same but in a different way. You can use constructor ready() for the same.

```
ready() {
super.ready();
const link = document.createElement("link");
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.type = "text/css";
link.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
link.href =
  "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Megrim";
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

}